# Create Folders in Library when submitting a list form in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I would like to know if it's possible to create folders when submitting a form in SharePoint. I created a custom SharePoint list form in Infopath and I want to add an action to the submit button to create four folders, one for each of the four doc libraries, that contains the title of the submitted item.

I see however that the custom code button is not enabled for a SharePoint list in Infopath so I cannot add any code in the background. The workflows that come out of the box also does not allow me to do it, unless I'm missing something...What other way is there to do it?

Thanks in advance for any help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do this, however, it's quite tricky.

In theory, you could call the "UpdateListItems" method of the Lists.asmx web service and pass a batch statement but due the implementation of the Lists web service you cannot use it in InfoPath. That's why you need to write your own web service that wraps the UpdateListItems method so you can use it with IP.

If you do not know how to write a web service (and host it within SharePoint) please use the search function of StackOverflow or consider google - many great tutorials out there ;-)

Once you got the web service running, you need to add a service reference to the http://myserver/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx web service and then create the following method:

```
[WebMethod]
public void UpdateListItems(string listGuid, string xmlBatch)
{
    var batch = new XmlDocument();
    batch.LoadXml(xmlBatch);

    //create an instance of the lists proxy client
    var listSvc = listService = new ListsWebService.Lists();

    //set the url of the client 
    listService.Url = "http://myserver/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx";

    listSvc.UpdateListItems(listGuid, batch);
}
```

**Note that if you configure the listSvc's Url hardcoded (like in this example), you need to make sure that the List, you want to add the folders to, is within the same site as the Url.** If you want to make it this method more generic (which i'd suggest you do), you could simply pass the SiteCollection Url as a parameter and set listSvc.Url to SiteCollectionUrl + "_vti_bin/Lists.asmx".

Once this is set up, you can create the data connection to your newly created web service in InfoPath and configure it like this: 
[image: Configuration of the Lists wrapper data connection]

The field "listName" is actually the GUID of the List - you can get it via the UI by clicking "Library Settings" - "Information management policy settings" and then copy it from the address bar in your browser. Example:

```
{39d01277-4ba1-4589-90f8-c957b4b2dd09}
```

The field "XML" contains the batch script to create the folder. You can declare it staticly, or in your case, you can build it dynamically using the concat() function. This example creates a folder named "MyFolder" in the root of the Library.

```
<Batch>
    <Method ID='1' Cmd='New'>
        <Field Name='ID'>New</Field>
        <Field Name='FSObjType'>1</Field>
        <Field Name='BaseName'>MyFolder</Field>
    </Method>
</Batch>
```

If you need to have sub-folders, this is possible too. This following example will create a folder named "MySubFolder" within the folder "MyFolder".

```
<Batch>
    <Method ID='1' Cmd='New'>
        <Field Name='ID'>New</Field>
        <Field Name='FSObjType'>1</Field>
        <Field Name='BaseName'>MyFolder/MySubFolder</Field>
    </Method>
</Batch>
```

Then you simply add a submit button action and you're done :-)

Also note that the code above is just an example (which works though). If you use it in production be sure to add proper exception logging because you'll be needing it :-)

hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Andreas!

I'll explore the web service idea. I'm no developer, but I'm sure I'll come right:) 

Will update the post as soon as I come right

Comment: Ah ok i didn't know.... you might wanna pass this to your favourite sharepoint dev ;-)

Comment: haha, yeah, I think so. I'm sure one of our developers would like a pet project:-) Thanks for the help!

Comment: glad to help. let me know if you need further assistance :-)